# Latex3: handling of sub-functions with shared name sub-parameters

Tags: expl3, arguments, keycommand

I am using latex3 to write a set of macros. I have defined the **nomeclature** class, and a **nominal case** which comprehends all the possible combinations to be used in the **test cases_i** ( i = 1:N ).

Now I want to create N **test cases** of the nominal. In some cases the parameter names are shared accros sub-functions (eg. mod, modd). The macro only works if the parameters are directly inputed by the user, but when defining the constants as follows

```
  typ .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { I=\bar }, 
  typ .initial:n = \bar,
```

it fails (it saves the value of the last case).

Here is a very simplified version of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ------------------------  Load needed packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{bm}

% ------------------------  Macro definition 
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Nominal case
\keys_define:nn { notation / nom }
 {
  I .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_I_tl,
  J .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_J_tl,
  K .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_K_tl,
  L .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_L_tl,
  I .initial:n = {},
  J .initial:n = {},
  K .initial:n = {},
  L .initial:n = {},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:      % Symbol % Modifiers   
  \nom_notation_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }%
  \group_end:%
 }

\cs_new:Nn \nom_notation_nom:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { #2 }
   \gennom{#1}
   {\l_nom_notation_L_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_I_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_J_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_K_tl}
 }

% First case
\keys_define:nn { notation / caseone }
 {
  mod .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { J=#1 },
  modd .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { K=#1 },
  id .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { L=#1 },
  typ .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { I=\bar }, 
  typ .initial:n = \bar,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\caseone}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { notation / caseone } { #2 }
  \nom{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
 
% Second case
\keys_define:nn { notation / casetwo }
 {
  mod .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { J=#1 },
  modd .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { K=#1 },
  id .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { L=#1 },
  typ .code:n = \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { I=\acute }, 
  typ .initial:n = \acute,
 }

  \NewDocumentCommand{\casetwo}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { notation / casetwo } { #2 }
  \nom{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% ------------------------ Main arrangement macros
\newcommand\gennom[5]{ {#5{#4{#3{#1}}}}_{#2} } 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\vec, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\acute, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\bar, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \caseone{a}[ mod=\dot, modd=\hat, id=guid ] } \\
{ \casetwo{a}[ mod=\dot, modd=\hat, id=guid ] } 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Which prints the following output:

Output:

[image]

It seems to be a fairly simple mistake. But my lack of knowledge has not allowed me to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a misconception of what `.initial:n` does. It just calls the key once with the given value, so `typ .initial:n = \bar` is the same as doing `\keys_set:nn {<set>} { typ = \bar }` at that place (and nowhere else).

Instead, you'll want to prepend your given keys with `typ` in each call of `\caseone` and `\casetwo`.

Also, note that there is a `.meta:nn` key to let one key set another key in another set/path, that should be preferred over doing `\keys_set:nn { <other-set> } { <key> = #1 }`. And if you forward a value to a single key you should use `<key> = {#1}` instead of `<key> = #1` (if `#1` contains a comma the version without braces leads to undefined behaviour).

Put together:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ------------------------  Load needed packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{bm}

% ------------------------  Macro definition 
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Nominal case
\keys_define:nn { notation / nom }
 {
  I .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_I_tl,
  J .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_J_tl,
  K .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_K_tl,
  L .tl_set:N = \l_nom_notation_L_tl,
  I .initial:n = {},
  J .initial:n = {},
  K .initial:n = {},
  L .initial:n = {},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:      % Symbol % Modifiers   
  \nom_notation_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }%
  \group_end:%
 }

\cs_new:Nn \nom_notation_nom:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { notation / nom } { #2 }
   \gennom{#1}
   {\l_nom_notation_L_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_I_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_J_tl}
   {\l_nom_notation_K_tl}
 }

% First case
\keys_define:nn { notation / caseone }
 {
  mod .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { J={#1} },
  modd .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { K={#1} },
  id .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { L={#1} },
  typ .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { I=\bar }, 
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\caseone}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { notation / caseone } { typ, #2 }
  \nom{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
 
% Second case
\keys_define:nn { notation / casetwo }
 {
  mod .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { J={#1} },
  modd .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { K={#1} },
  id .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { L={#1} },
  typ .meta:nn = { notation / nom } { I=\acute }, 
 }

  \NewDocumentCommand{\casetwo}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { notation / casetwo } { typ, #2 }
  \nom{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% ------------------------ Main arrangement macros
\newcommand\gennom[5]{ {#5{#4{#3{#1}}}}_{#2} } 

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\vec, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\acute, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \nom{\Theta}[ I=\bar, J=\dot, K=\hat, L=L ] } \\
{ \caseone{a}[ mod=\dot, modd=\hat, id=guid ] } \\
{ \casetwo{a}[ mod=\dot, modd=\hat, id=guid ] }
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation @Skillmon, I tried the changes in the original code and it works perfectly :)!